# "Cannot GET / " after initial running of project

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, ecmascript-6

My angular 7 , .net core project is getting error "Cannot GET /" on first running of project.
After server started when i just save any of my angular 7 files in editor, the browser reloads and working fine, but on initial starting its getting error.
There are no Errors found on client side or server side.

Did anyone came across such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “Cannot GET / ” after initial running of project

I have encounter this issue everytime when I run ASP.Net Core and Angular template. It's because when we run ASP.Net Core server it will run 2 port 1 port for ASP.Net Core server and 1 port for Angular.

The Angular port will have to build and bundle everything so it may take time to bootstrap angular app and sometime we will have time out issue lead to “Cannot GET / ” after initial running of project. So my recommend is you navigate to ClientApp folder run

```
ng serve
```

and wait until everything is done build then you can run ASP.Net Core using visual studio by ctrl + f5

Comment: Hi, Iam getting this error on first running of project.

after server started if i just saved any of the angular files in editor then its working fine.

Comment: Me too. So i just give a way to work around it. You can run ng serve in ClientApp folder and wait before bundle finished then run your asp.net core web server